# Parsing a xml file using simplexml and accessing properties

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a xml file which has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <uclassify xmlns="http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema" version="1.00">
  <status success="true" statusCode="2000" /> 
- <readCalls>
- <classify id="cls1">
- <classification>
  <class className="Arts" p="0.920034" /> 
  <class className="Business" p="2.81823e-005" /> 
  <class className="Computers" p="0.0040341" /> 
  <class className="Games" p="0.00846496" /> 
  <class className="Health" p="0.00203198" /> 
  <class className="Home" p="0.00136572" /> 
  <class className="Recreation" p="0.000526926" /> 
  <class className="Science" p="0.000160703" /> 
  <class className="Society" p="0.0611354" /> 
  <class className="Sports" p="0.00221835" /> 
  </classification>
  </classify>
  </readCalls>
  </uclassify>
```

I am trying to access the properties className and p in class.
This is the code that I have so far:

```
$resXml = simplexml_load_file($requestUrl); //$requestUrl is where the xml file is located
$children = $resXml->children('http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema');

foreach ($children->readCalls->classify->classification->class as $d) {
    $currClassificationName = $d['className'];
    $currClassificationRating = (float) $d['p'];
    echo "$currClassificationName: $currClassificationRating" . "</br>";
}
```

This is the output:

```
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
: 0
```

The output I am trying to get is:

```
Arts: 0.920034
Business: 2.81823e-005 
  ... 
Society: 0.0611354
Sports: 0.00221835
```

Been trying different things for a while and cannot figure this out. Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$resXml = simplexml_load_file($requestUrl); //$requestUrl is where the xml file is located

foreach ($resXml->readCalls->classify->classification->class as $d) {
    $currClassificationName = $d['className'];
    $currClassificationRating = (float) $d['p'];
    echo "$currClassificationName: $currClassificationRating" . "</br>";
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you for the help, I was going nuts trying to figure this out. I was trying to model my code after an example I found and didn't really know what I was doing with "$children = $resXml->children('http://api.uclassify.com/1/ResponseSchema');"

Comment: did you managed to parse data with php library from uclassify?